# Found duplicate classes/resources in runtime classpath

Tags: maven, class, build, duplicates, runtime

I added an aritifact dependency in my pom after which the mvn clean install command fails with the below error. Can someone please suggest how to resolve it? Thanks all :)

```
[WARNING] Found duplicate and different classes in [jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:2.0.2, javax.validation:validation-api:2.0.1.Final]:
```

Comment: *fails with the below error* This is only a warning. And the message is pretty clear

Comment: It will help us, if you can give us more detailed information. for instance your pom and which artefact you have added

Comment: *Can someone please suggest how to resolve it?* exclude `javax.validation:validation-api` from the newly added dependency

Comment: Please show you pom file? You have added a dependency and now have two different artifacts on the classpath which are mutal exclusive means only one of them is allowed so you have to clean up your deps...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using eclipse, please open the `pom.xml`

There is a tab called `Dependency Hierarchy`. Go there and filter for the term `validation-api`. You will find two entries (maybe more). Right-Click on one entrie (maybe the older) and choose `Exclude Maven Artifact` may solve your problem.